# Cypress don't open download link popup with jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, cypress

I have an issue. When I want to download a file with Cypress I don't want Cypress to open the popup of downloading and clicking enter outside the browser. So I wrote this;

```
selectDownloadOfAssets() {

let $download = Cypress.$('.fa-download').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();  
                window.location.href = 'uploads/text.txt';
                   cy.wrap($download).trigger('click', { force : true })

   });
}
```

But it looks like Cypress just skips this part when calling the function selectDownloadOfAssets() so this second "solution" looks in the Cypress runner that it works, but it does not do anything. At least I don't see anything change in the UI.

```
   const forceClickEl = () => {
        let x = Cypress.$('.fa-download').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = 'uploads/text.txt';
        });
        return x
    };
    cy.wrap({name: forceClickEl}).invoke('name');
```

Does anybody have an idea why this is not working or what I am missing?

Cheers